# Syncing fails after changing Google Apps user's email

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-apps

A few days ago, I changed the primary email of a Google Apps user from user@domaina.com to user@domainb.com

Ever since doing so, Android refuses to sync using either the new or old email address, but I can still log in on the web using both.

Both domains are controlled by my Google Apps organization, and attempting to reconnect the accounts after a factory reset gives me an incorrect password error.

The device is running Android 2.3.3 if it makes a difference.

Comment: Have you tried changing the password, and trying to log-in again with the new password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized last night that since I have 2 factor auth enabled for my account, I might have to generate a new application-specific password in my google account settings.

I generated a new one and successfully synced with my new email using it.